# How to transpose pivot data set like this (Pivot data already)

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, transpose, unpivot

I have data set as below:

[image: Initial data set in SQL Server]

And I need to transpose data like (I use Excel transpose):

[image: Result expect in SQL Server]

How to do that in SQL Server with `PIVOT` or `UNPIVOT` relational operators? I have tried, but no success.

Thanks

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not have any real DDL statements from you, maybe you can try out this fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=894cfaad640a086dff7b419ae934f9aa)** or see the query below.
The below query uses [unpivoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms177410(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) followed by pivoting to get the job done.

```
select * from 
(select * from Temp
)s
unpivot
(datavalues for cols in ([2],[2],[3],[4],[5]))u
pivot 
(sum(datavalues) for [programType] in ([hp],[load]))p
```

alternately you can also use group with case to get same output like

```
select 
cols, sum(case when programType ='hp' then datavalues end) as [hp], 
sum(case when programType ='load' then datavalues end) as [load]
from 
(select * from Temp
)s
unpivot
(datavalues for cols in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]))u
group by cols
```

Comment: Hi' DhruvJoshi, It works perfectly. I never know it can refer to "datavalues for cols" like this. I just think it must be value in the column only, Thank a lot sir.